# When is it appropriate to use multiple destinations in a single assignment?

Tags: c#, variable-assignment

I occasionally see this:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;

a = b = 3;  //assign 3 to a and b.
```

I think it is not a good idea, but I do see it done. It seems like it is better to state

```
a = 3;
b = 3;
```

This way, it is clear to later readers that this is what is occurring.

Should assignments like these be avoided, or are there situations when such assignments would be preferred?

**Edit**
After reviewing the comments and answer, I think a more accurate question is:
Is IntA = IntB = 3 the same as splitting onto multiple lines?

The answer, for primitive types, is yes, it is the same.  So to use or not to use is preference.

For reference types, the answer is no, it is not the same.

ref = ref = new Ref() results in two references to the same object.

```
ref = new Ref();
ref = new Ref();
```

results in two new objects.  So it is legal to use if two object references is what your really intended. Beyond that, it is preference.

I see no other differences between the two.

Comment: Matter of opinion, not relevant to SO.

Comment: I disagree, best practices are important to coding, and this is what I am asking.

Comment: This is more a coding standard... I generally avoid multiple assignments. They're difficult to debug and error prone.

Comment: Try [Programmers.StackExchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design-patterns)

Comment: It's not simply a matter of opinion, because there are gotchas, as Eric Lippert pointed out here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/02/11/chaining-simple-assignments-is-not-so-simple.aspx

Comment: @GregHollywood - [StackExchange - Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a better place for this question

Comment: @Tim: Pros and cons are objective, but whether the pros outweigh the cons is subjective, and so is the question asked: "should I avoid this practice?"

Comment: Largely a matter of opinion, but there's a difference between `Widget a,b; a = b = new Widget() ;` and `Widget a = new Widget() ; Widget b = new Widget() ;`. In the former, `a` and `b` both have references to the same `Widget` instance; in the latter `a` and `b` have references to different instances of `Widget`.

Comment: I'm with Greg on this one, this is the sort of question I run into when I'm coding as well.  Though, as Myndwave said, it may be better on Programmers.SE

Comment: @Karl: I strongly disagree.  Code Review is for code that compiles, not tiny snippets.

Comment: @BenVoigt - fair enough, definitely not fit for SO though.

Comment: @GregHollywood Perhaps rephrase it away from "best practice" and towards a "practical considerations" question. I.e. "is it a matter of opinion/preference or are there practical issues to consider in choosing one over the other?".

Comment: I had an answer for you, but then it closed. Oh well.

Comment: I edited the question as suggested by Bart.

Comment: @Myndwave, Kal_Torak: No.

Comment: @Tim, I can't see how that blog post proof it's not simply an opinion based?

Comment: @gdoron because he lists specific places where it is not simply a pass-through as people assume. If there are clear "gotchas" I think that takes it out of straight opinion and at least into "informed opinion" which might actually be reasonable here.

Comment: My answer, put simply, is no. I don't think it's bad practice for primitive types to be assigned the same value on the same line. When you're debugging to find out where a variable gets it's value from, you're going to be searching through the code, or you can simply use the Find All References feature. Using either method, you'll have the same amount of difficulty finding it on the same line as you would on different lines. As far as primitive types are concerned, I do believe it is only a matter of opinion.

Comment: @seekerOfKnowledge, I would still like to hear what you have to say.

Comment: Commented just mere seconds before you did. :)

Comment: @Tim, not convinced...

Comment: @BoltClock, If it's not appropriate for either here OR Programmers.SE, where then would you suggest it be asked?  It's a legitimate question even if it doesn't meet SO criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are situations when multiple assignments are definitely inappropriate. For example, the following should never be done:

```
decimal speed;
decimal distance;
speed = distance = 0M; // <<== This compiles, but it is very, very wrong.
```

There are situations when multi-assignments provide for better readability - specifically, when you are assigning the same object instance to two variables before going into an algorithm that may or may not leave them "pointing" at the same object:

```
// You can do this
MyClass smallest;
MyClass largest;
smallest = new MyClass();
largest = smallest;
// However, this conveys the idea slightly better:
MyClass smallest;
MyClass largest;
smallest = largest = new MyClass();
```

Though technically it is not the same, a related situation when multi-assignment provides for better readability is when you cache a result:

```
MyClass res = cached ?? (cached = Compute());
```

In this case the assignment of `Compute()` to `res` also changes `cached`, unless `cached` is non-null to begin with.

Comment: Nice job getting your answer in there just before the door was closed yet again. lol. Also, I believe, as I stated in the comments, that primitive types are the only variable types that I would assign on the same line. Guess this topic is largely opinion based.

Comment: Your answer shows why the question should be closed, _"This compiles, but it is very, very wrong."_ I think it's fine. opinion based only!

Comment: @gdoron You're kidding! Do you *really* think that assigning `distance` to `speed` is OK simply because they happen to be represented by the same number?

Comment: If there is a reason why they both have the same value, or else why would you assign one to the other...? maybe the example was just bad or I didn't understand the point you tried to point.

Comment: @gdoron My point was that the speed can never be equal to a distance, simply because they represent different things. They could both be equal to zero, but the speed would be equal to zero meters per second, while the distance would be equal to zero meters (or whatever units you may prefer). The fact that the units are omitted from the program does not change much, because they are implicit to your human readers. It is the same to the computer, but it a reader who is trying to follow your thought would be baffled at why you are mixing your units.